# Releasing build issues React native Expo

Tags: react-native, android-studio

"react-native-expo does not update the code in releasing build android studio. successfully run in debug mode but releasing built not use updated code
Please Help

Comment: Did you run the bundle command?

Comment: yes after the expo publish use android build steps

Answer (score 0):

- Use expo publish command, to make the changes to server side or try using the bundle command and run from android studio.

Comment: can you plz explain this how to change the server side because  i m using react native expo 27.0.1 and after the expo publish use build steps in android but updated code not Apply in release APK file  #Rishav Kumar